# How to download a file from php, when it is stored in mysql table as a TEXT, not blob?

Tags: php, mysql, download

I also want to be able to format the extension, for instance to add .xml or something to it.
I know how to download a blob file, with all the filesize, name etc. (changing headers), but do I need the same for just a text file?

Comment: Doesn't matter where the data comes from, you use the same headers and setup. then it's either `echo $blob` or `readfile($filename)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this.  I would setup a table 'files' like this:

```
CREATE TABLE  'files' (
id INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
extension VARCHAR( 4 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'txt',
content_type VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text/plain',
data VARCHAR( 100000 ) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id) );
```

download.php code:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['id']);
$SELECT = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($SELECT, $link);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

header("content-type: $result['content_type']");
echo $result['data'];
```

html:

```
<a href="download.php?id=$_GET['id']">download file</a>
```

Comment: Pass in an id url param to download.php -

Comment: @makudex - $link is a mysqli connection, you need to pass that connection in - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php.  id is a url param passed into download.php - for example: http://your_host/download.php?id=1.  The select made, the content type header is set, then the data is returned.

Here's how you would insert a JSON file:
INSERT INTO files (id, content_type, data) values (10, 'text/json', "object:{prop1:'val1',prop2:'val2'}");

To return the content: 
http://hostname/download.php?id=10